# Force id value when using SequenceGenerator in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement in which I have to store a new record in the table with the ID that I send manually. Now in my hibernate entity file I use @SequenceGenerator and @GeneratedValue, so when i try to save, even though I try passing a ID I am getting a new ID being generated. I need to know if there is any way that we have where when we pass Id to the entity the new sequence not be created but the new record will be created with the id that is being passed to the entity. Given below is my Entity

### Subject.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
public class Subject {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "SUBJECT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_SUBJECT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")})
    private Consignee consignee;
            
    @Column(name="SUBJECT_NAME")
    private String subjectName;

    //Getters and Setters           
}
```

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` simply means that Hibernate generates the ID for you. So, don't put that annotation on the field, if you want to set it manually.

Comment: I need such a way that it should get Generated when there is no id set. When id is set I do not want a new Id to get generated

Comment: @DeepakRamakrishnanKalidass What database do you use?

Comment: If you set the ID manually, it will cause a conflict give you errors if the sequence ever reaches up to that ID. I have lived through that, so unless you're importing data from a foreign database, setting the ID manually is a bad idea, and even then it's better to adjust the sequence counter instead.

Comment: Does this help , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194845/how-to-override-sequencegeneratorname-idgenerator-sequencename-hiberna