# JPA persist entity but ignore sequence for certain use case

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf

I have a JPA Entity `Report` mapped to an existing legacy database table that stores meta data about paper reports and uses two primary keys to make a record unique.

```
  ReportId (PK)
  ReportRev (PK)
```

`ReportId` uses an existing Oracle sequence and `ReportRev` is a string for the Revision letter of the Report.

Occasionally a paper report is revised and the meta data for the revision needs to be recorded using the original `ReportId` but with the next ReportRev.

```
For example:  
Report  1234 Rev - (Author, date signed, Approved By, Title, etc...)
Report  1235 Rev - 
Report  1236 Rev - 
Report  1237 Rev -
Report  1234 Rev A
```

`Rev -` is the initial Report and subsequent revisions go from Rev dash to A to B to C, etc.. ​

I am able to persist the initial Report Record.  I leave the ReportId blank and set ReportRev to dash and the Entity Manager sets the Id using the sequence. No problem there.

But how to I persist the revision?

If I set the ReportId to the original ReportId and set the ReportRev to the next applicable letter, the Entity Manager still uses the sequence.

I was hoping that if I actually set the `ReportId` the EntityManager would override/skip using the Oracle sequence.

How can I persist an entity using an existing `ReportId` but with a new `ReportRev` that maintains uniqueness?

The only thing I can think of is to use a `NativeQuery` to perform the revision inserts. But then I'll have to manually map the entity and that reminds me of the old JSP days :(

---

Here is how I currently have it modelled:

```
@IdClass(ReportPK.class)
public class Report implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long reportId;

    @Id
    private String reportRev;
```

I don't think using @Version annotation is applicable here, btw, as we don't want to keep track of every edit of a record.

```
public class ReportPK implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "REPORT_NUMBER")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    private Long reportId;

    @Id
    private String reportRev;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do does not work the SequenceGenerator because this always generates a new sequence for a new entity. You should set the reportId by using the sequence in the code.

Comment: Annotations don't belong in the ReportPK class - they belong on the entity itself. Add the sequence annotation on the reportId in Report and see if it helps. There should be no problem with you persisting an entity with an existing reportId long, using a different reportRev string in this manner -other providers use the existence of a value there to decide if it must assign a value or not, while Hibernate doesn't seem to. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209206/496099

Comment: moving all annotations out of the IdClass caused ORA-01400 Cannot insert NULL into ReportNum.  The seq is not getting used now on simple initial Report persist.  One thing not shown in my code is I am also using Column annotation on the ReportId attribute.  The legacy db column is a different.  So even playing around with where the Column annotation was still produced the ORA error.  I'm still investigating the content from your link, but

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can you provide a little more details on exactly what you mean?  Are you suggesting a Native Query?

Comment: Yes a native query to select the next value from the sequence